# .NET Core, VS2019, and Selenium: IE Driver Doesn't Work (WebDriverException - HTTP request timeout)

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

**UPDATE:** This error only happens in Visual Studio 2019. I'm on 16.3.1 Community. Visual Studio 2017 works just fine and causes no issues. So it seems the crux of the issue lies in Visual Studio 2019 for some reason.

**NOTE** that no matter which IDE I build it in, `dotnet run` will fail just like VS2019 does. Only if I run the app within VS2017 does it work.

I [cross-posted this to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/748198/selenium-iedriverserver-fails.html) via Visual Studio's built-in "Report a Problem" menu to attack this issue from multiple angles. I'll report back if/when they do anything (i.e. if they identify it as an issue with Visual Studio).

---

We've recently upgraded from .NET Framework to .NET Core. The application presently runs on .NET Core 2.2, but the same issues occur on .NET Core 3.0.

We run Selenium for UI testing, and for some reason, Internet Explorer's tests are quite wonky. The driver successfully launches the browser, but the first `Navigate()` call hangs indefinitely after it successfully performs navigation (never gets beyond that line of code). Here's the full stack trace:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
>   HResult=0x80131500
>
> Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52211/session/9e1e828b-5e72-46d8-8012-6b29bfc2d854/url timed out after 10 seconds.
>     Source=WebDriver
>
> StackTrace:
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
>
> at SandboxSelenium.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev_sandbox\SandboxSelenium\SandboxSelenium\Program.cs:line 17
>
> Inner Exception 1: WebException: The operation has timed out.

For simplicity, I created a brand new .NET Core Console App, and did nothing in Main except repeat the above step, and I recreated the issue.

Here are the whole csproj of the console app project, including package references:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver" Version="3.150.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And here's the code I'm calling:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SandboxSelenium
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); // In .NET Core you have to tell Selenium where the EXE is.
            InternetExplorerOptions opts = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(binPath, opts, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)))
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/"); // "Line 17" in above error. This line times out!
                IWebElement someTextbox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SomeTextBox")); // Never gets here...
                someTextbox.SendKeys("abc123");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I only set the driver's command timeout to `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)` (10 seconds) in order to shorten the timeout from the default 60 seconds. It times out no matter how long or short the timeout is.

Also, it seems the server executable, `IEDriverServer.exe`, doesn't close either and is left hanging open after the crash.

**I suspect** that somehow Selenium is losing track of IE or something, since it seems to completely lose the browser itself. Not sure though. **I have tried** changing the `PageLoadStrategy` within `InternetExplorerOptions` for the driver, but that didn't help any. I **have also tried** using the 64bit NuGet package for the IE server driver, but that didn't change anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For anyone wondering, I was able to reproduce the exact issue. I will try to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks @Christine and good luck!

Comment: It’s weird because IE will actually navigate to the URL, then it times out afterwards like it’s waiting for something else. I read another post suggesting to update `PageLoadStrategy` to `Eager` but that didn’t work.

Comment: I would recommend opening a GitHub issue in the Selenium repo for this. There's no discernible reason why the code isn't working, and the Selenium devs might point you to a special setting that could help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and managed to solve this by running VS2019 as an administrator, the same worked for command line.

Answer (score 0):

> using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(binPath, opts, new
>   TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)))

The issue is relate to the InternetExplorerDriver setting (the above code). Please check the [InternetExplorerDriver Constructor (String, InternetExplorerOptions, TimeSpan)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IE_InternetExplorerDriver__ctor_7.htm) method, we can see that the TimeSpan means the maximum amount of time to wait for each command. if the waiting time is over, it will show this error.

To prevent this error, you could try to extend the waiting time or remove this setting. Code as below:

```
        using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(binPath, opts))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/"); // "Line 17" in above error. This line times out!
            IWebElement someTextbox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q")); // Never gets here...
            someTextbox.SendKeys("abc123"); 
        }
```

**Edit**:

You could extend the waiting time, such as set it to 20 seconds.

Besides, when we use the SendKeys method to enter values into the textbox, it might be very slow and spend too much time. As a workaround, to decrease the spend time, we could use the IJavaScriptExecutor to execute the JavaScript script, and set the value.

Code as below:

```
        using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(binPath, opts, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20)))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/"); // "Line 17" in above error. This line times out!
            //IWebElement someTextbox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q")); // Never gets here...
            //someTextbox.SendKeys("abc123");
            var element = driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");

            var script = "document.getElementById('sb_form_q').value = 'webdriver';";
            IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

            jse.ExecuteScript(script, element); 
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter); 
        }
```

Comment: Apologies. I only set the timeout to 10 seconds because it was wasteful waiting for the default timeout length of 60 seconds. Removing the timeout sadly just makes the code take longer to fail. I should've mentioned this in my original post!

Comment: Please check the Edit, you could try to extend the waiting time or using the IJavaScriptExecutor to execute the JavaScript script to decrease the spend time. Another point, please check the navigate url, whether the url is correct and whether it spends too much time to load or not? You could try to test my code first, to check whether it works well.

Comment: Sorry, the timeout is not the issue, as I've pointed out already. The default timeout (60 seconds) times out too, and it doesn't even get to `SendKeys`. It times out on the Navigate line.

Comment: how much time the website will spend to load the page? Have you ever used the F12 developer tools to check it? might be you need to improve website performance and decrease the page load time.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it appears you are missing Microsoft Web driver. If you are using Windows OS I recommend go to <**settings**> --> select **Update  & Security**, then to the left from the list choose **For developers** and finally click & select **Developers mode** and wait for the installation to complete and then run your project. I also recommend using EdgeDriver instead of InternetExploperDriver
I hope this helps!